# MS Report builder how to select only the required cells?

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-reporting

How do I select only cells? For example, if we choose only B2 and B6, let's add and subtract each other because I can only go through all columns, for example A2,A6.
B2,B6
C2,C6 How do we select only cell B?

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit your question and show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, something missing in your question and while corrected, what is the control you used for this in reporting? Are you already created this in report and only selected thing you want?